# How to redirect using .htaccess using Apache?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

Please help me to redirect using .htaccess like below.

http://info.domainname.com/blog/?Tag=somedynamictag

to

http://domainname.com/tag/somedynamictag

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First of all I don't understand the purpose of rewriting http://info.domainname.com/blog/?Tag=somedynamictag to http://domainname.com/tag/somedynamictag when it had to be the other way round. People rewrite URLs to clean them (ie. remove characters like `?`,`&`,`=`, etc.) but you are adding all these and making the URLs cumbersome.

I think you didn't properly understand the concept of URL rewriting. Let me explain a little.

When any URL is accessed on your website, the URL that the USER types or clicks (in your case http://domainname.com/tag/somedynamictag) is rewritten. But your question tells me that you think the other way. Your understanding is that the visitor clicks  http://info.domainname.com/blog/?Tag=somedynamictag and will be rewritten to http://domainname.com/tag/somedynamictag. **THIS IS WRONG!!.** If you set up your website this way, each and every URL at http://domain.com/ must exist as a separate file or directory which a dynamic website like you seem to be developing is not expected to have. So I assume you have understood that you have either misformed the question or you have you have misunderstood the concept of URL rewriting. Following is the .htaccess code to redirect http://domainname.com/tag/somedynamictag to http://info.domainname.com/blog/?Tag=somedynamictag.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} domainname.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9]+)\/(.*)$ http://info.domainname.com/blog/?$1=$2 [L,R=301]
```

If you think you have correctly typed the question and understood url-rewriting right and are sure what you are trying to do is right, then here's the htaccess code (if you want to redirect http://info.domainname.com/blog/?Tag=somedynamictag to http://domainname.com/tag/somedynamictag).

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} info.domainname.com
RewriteRule ^blog\/\?([A-Za-z0-9]+)=(.*)$ http://domainname.com/$1/$2 [L,R=301]
```

If that doesn't work, in index.php at http://info.domainname.com/blog/, place the following code:

```
<?php
header("HTTP/1.1 301 moved permanently");
header("Location:http://domainname.com/blog/tag/".$_GET['Tag']);
?>
```

And thank you for asking this question. While answering it, I learned many things.

Hope that answers your question,

Peace...

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I am getting internal server error after adding your code. .htaccess file as below


# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - 

[L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php 

[L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} info.domainname.com
RewriteRule ^blog\/\?([A-Za-z0-9]+)\=(.*)$ http://domainname.com/$1/$2 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress

Thank you!

Comment: have you enabled mod_rewrite?